# Proper way of using form input to redirect to a url in Django

Tags: python, django

I managed to get the value from an HTML form to a URL pattern but it wasn't an elegant way of solving the problem. So I'm asking what is the better way to do that, since I'm faced with the same problem again.

Here's a simplified version of what I had:

My **HTML form**:

```
<form method='post' action={% url 'pressed_button' %}>
  <button name="choice" value="Correct-Button"> Click Me </button>
  <button name="choice" value="Wrong-Button"> Dont Click Me </button>
</form>
```

Here's my **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^PressedButton/$', views.PressedButtonView.as_view(), name='pressed_button'),
url(r'^PressedButton/(?P<choice>\w+)$', views.PressedButtonView.as_view(), name='pressed_button_with_user_choice'),
```

and the view class **PressedButtonView**:

```
class PressedButtonView(View):
    def get(self, request, choice):
        return render(request, 'weirdapp/buttonclicked.html', {'button': choice})

    def post(self, request):
        choice = request.POST['choice']

        return redirect(reverse('pressed_button_with_user_choice', kwargs={'choice': choice}))
```

---

Now, I thought if I could just send the value of the pressed button in the "action" attribute of the form

```
<form method='post' action={% url 'pressed_button_with_user_choice' 'pressedButtonValue' %}>
```

it will be a lot nicer code.

Also, if I could get an answer to my secondary-but-related question, what does the reverse method in `return redirect(reverse())` do? Why not just redirect to a URL pattern name?

Thanks.

Comment: The `reverse` method returns a url. You can use it with `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(...))`. However, you don't need to use `reverse` with the `redirect` shortcut. You can simplify `redirect(reverse('pressed_button_with_user_choice', kwargs={'choice': choice}))` to `return redirect('pressed_button_with_user_choice', choice=choice)`.

Comment: @Alasdair oh I see.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to answer my own question after a while because I thought of a good solution.

Using Javascript we could send the POST request of the form's data to the url we want using values that we get from the button that was pressed. Here's how:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="my-form">
 Age: <input name="age" value="31"/>
</form>

<button class="form-submitter" data-choice="Correct-Button"> Click Me </button>
<button class="form-submitter" data-choice="Wrong-Button"> Dont Click Me </button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
(function(){
  $('.form-submitter').on('click', function(e){
    let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('my-form'));
    let buttonChoice = $(this).data('choice');

    $.ajax({
      url: '/PressedButton/ + buttonChoice',
      data: formData,
      method: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(response){
        console.log("successful communication", response);
      },
    });

  });  
})();
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^PressedButton/(?P<choice>\w+)$', views.PressedButtonView.as_view(), name='pressed_button'),
```

in view class **PressedButtonView:**

```
class PressedButtonView(View):
    def post(self, request, choice):
        #age = request.POST['age']
        return render(request, 'weirdapp/buttonclicked.html', {'button': choice})
```

Here's a more documented JSFiddle of the javascript working.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3tf9mhu/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Why not make separate forms with proper `action` for each button?

Comment: Would that mean I wouldn't need two URL patterns?
And, it still doesn't feel 'pythonic'.

Comment: That eliminates the need for redirection. That is a problem that lies in the "web" part. Not in the "python" part. With no intermediate view there is nothing left to be or not to be "pythonic".

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest an alternative approach? Perhaps it would be better to validate the correct/incorrect choice after the form is `post`? In the `form_valid` you could then redirect to another page based on the correct/incorrect choice?

In other words, if you put hints in the HTML like `class=Correct-choice` you might get some cheaters :P

Comment: I'm still new to all this stuff so I just wanna make sure I understand you correctly. I should check the form's POST request content in a function inside the view that got called when the form was `post`ed. Then this function redirects to anther URL. Correct?

Comment: No you shouldn't directly access POST, [Read documentation on Class based views and you will see what I mean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)